Change.listen not triggering at app end when data inserted in mongoDB in flutter
I am working in a flutter where I am expecting the UI to be updated with data when backend insert any in mongoDB collection. For futter I am using realm.
Currently I am trying to listen changes in mongoDB but it is not triggering when data getting inserted in to the mongoDB
Pasting my code here.
class UserPlantRepo extends UserPlantRepoInterface {
  final RealmServiceInterface _realmService;

  final localDataStream = StreamController<RealmResultsChanges<UserPlant>?>.broadcast();


  UserPlantRepo({
    required RealmServiceInterface realmService,
  }) : _realmService = realmService
  {
    localDataStream.stream.listen((event) {
     log("UserPlantRepo localDataStream event emitted $event");
   },onError: (error){
     log("UserPlantRepo localDataStream error emitted $error");
   },);
  }



  @override
  Future<UserPlantDataModelWrapper> getUserPlantsFromDB(
      {required String emailAddress}) async {
    try {
      await _realmService.updateSubscriptions<UserPlant>(
        r'userId==$0',
        [emailAddress],
      );
      final RealmResults<UserPlant>? response = await _realmService.fetchData(
        r'userId==$0',
        [
          emailAddress,
        ],
      );

      if(response != null){
        log("UserPlantRepo getUserPlantsFromDB response is not null");
       localDataStream.addStream(response.changes);
      }
     ;
      if (response != null) {
        if (response.isNotEmpty) {
          return UserPlantDataModelWrapper(
              isSuccess: true,
              userPlantDataModel: response.first.getUserPlants());
        } else {
          return UserPlantDataModelWrapper(
              isSuccess: true, userPlantDataModel: null);
        }
      } else {
        return UserPlantDataModelWrapper(
            isSuccess: true, userPlantDataModel: null);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return UserPlantDataModelWrapper(
          isSuccess: true, userPlantDataModel: null);
    }
  }

  Stream<RealmResultsChanges<UserPlant>?> get getUpdateStatusStream => localDataStream.stream;
}

Please help on this.

We would love to help but it's important you perform some troubleshooting first. Add a breakpoint to your code then update the data being watched. Does the code trigger? If not, something is not set up correctly. If so, step through the code and determine where it's failing. Update your question with details and we'll take a look!
